# How to use jq to produce a cartesian product of two arrays present in the input JSON

Tags: arrays, json, jq, cartesian-product

I'd like to be able to use `jq` to output the 'product' of 2 arrays in the input JSON... for example, given the following input JSON:

```
 {
     "quantities": [
         {
             "product": "A",
             "quantity": 30
         },
         {
             "product": "B",
             "quantity": 10
         }
         ],
     "portions": [
         {
             "customer": "C1",
             "percentage": .6
         },
         {
             "customer": "C2",
             "percentage": .4
         }
     ]
 }
```

I'd like to produce the following output (or similar...):

```
[
    {
     "customer": "C1",
     "quantities": [
         {
             "product": "A",
             "quantity": 18
         },
         {
             "product": "B",
             "quantity": 6
         }
         ]
    },
    {
     "customer": "C2",
     "quantities": [
         {
             "product": "A",
             "quantity": 12
         },
         {
             "product": "B",
             "quantity": 4
         }
         ]
    }
]
```

So in other words, for each portion, use its value of percentage, and apply it to each product quantity.  Given 2 quantities and 2 portions should yield 4 results.. given 3 quantities and 2 portions should yield 6 results, etc...

I've made some attempts using `foreach` filters, but to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
[
  .quantities as $q
| .portions[]
| .percentage as $p
| {
    customer,
    quantities: [
       $q[] | .quantity = .quantity * $p
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated you want the Cartesian product, and that you only gave the sample output as being indicative of what you're looking for, it may be worth mentioning that one can obtain the Cartesian product very simply:

```
 .portions[] + .quantities[]
```

This produces objects such as:

```
{
  "product": "B",
  "quantity": 10,
  "customer": "C2",
  "percentage": 0.4
}
```

You could then use `reduce` or (less efficiently, `group_by`) to obtain the data in whatever form it is you really want.

For example, assuming .customer is always a string, we could transform
the input into the requested format as follows:

```
def add_by(f;g): reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);

[.quantities[] + .portions[]]
| map( {customer, quantities: {product, quantity: (.quantity * .percentage)}} )
| add_by(.customer; .quantities)
| to_entries
| map( {customer: .key, quantities: .value })
```